# How to cause a delay with ReactiveUI.Validation in a ValidationRule

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.reactive, reactiveui

I am doing the following:

`this.ValidationRule(vm => vm.UserEntry, this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.UserEntry, IsEntryValidOrEmpty).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)), "Invalid entry.")`

Expecting this

[image]

but the Delay() acts almost like a Throttle() - causing each change in validation status (true/false) to be delayed 5 seconds.

I would expect that the observable sequence would only be shifted once at the start by 5 seconds as this is how Delay() is supposed to work as I understand it.

but getting this

[image]

What I'd really like to do in the end is actually to introduce a 5 second delay between the first and second element of the sequence, not before the the first, but that's the next step.

this is what I really want
[image]

I have tried various variations on the the theme, but they all behave as if the sequence is restarted between each change in validation status. There's definitely something I'm not getting here.

Comment: `this.ValidationRule(
  vm => vm.UserEntry,
  this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.UserEntry, IsEntryValidOrEmpty)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)),
  "Invalid entry."
)`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of what you are trying to do. If possible, draw some kind of marble diagram when/how the generated items should be proceeded from the source observable to the target observable. Also explain why you need this 5 second delay.

Comment: Thank you, but how would adding a Throttle() help? The whole problem is that the Delay() already acts like a Throttle() in this context, causing a wait of 5 seconds between each of the elements of the sequence. I don't want that. I want to have a single 5 second delay, then no more. The net effect of this suggestion is to cause a 10 second wait between each validation status change. I tried it, and that's what happens.

Comment: Added some marble diagrams hopefully clarifying. As to why I need this delay, that's really beside the point, but it's similar to a debounce - I don't want the validation error to show up on the first character typed, because it's just annoying for the user who is in the process of typing. I want to give the user a reasonable amount of time to actually type something correct before informing them of an error. Yes, there are other ways to achieve similar net effects, for example not validating until hitting "Ok" etc, but I don't want that. I want this.

Comment: The problem appears to be that Delay() is simply so inefficient that the scheduling is so slow that it *appears* as if the 5-second delay is between each element. In fact, it's more of a 2-3 second delay. Still not very useful. What does work as expected, and efficiently, in this scenario is DelaySubscription() which does almost the same thing, but behaves much nicer in this scenario. The issue has nothing to do with ReactiveUI.Validation, the behavior was confirmed using a manual INotifyDataErrorInfo implementation.